# Syntax error in rvm bash scripts

Tags: rvm, bash

My `rvm` is not working, probably due to an error. When I open new console, it says:

```
-bash: /Users/amorfis/.rvm/scripts/cd: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/amorfis/.rvm/scripts/cd: line 14: `    cd()    { __zsh_like_cd cd    "$@" ; }'
```

It's hard to say where the script `.rvm/scripts/cd` is called. When I remove this line from `~/.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

there is no error. But when I issue `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`... still there is no error.

My system is Mac OS X 10.9.4

rvm --version:

`rvm 1.25.29 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

UPDATE

Other scripts in ~/.rvm/scripts:

```
alias
aliases
autolibs
base
cd
cleanup
cli
completion
cron
db
disk-usage
docs
env
extras
fetch
fix-permissions
functions
gemsets
group
hash
help
hook
info
initialize
install
irbrc
irbrc.rb
list
maglev
manage
migrate
monitor
mount
notes
osx-ssl-certs
override_gem
patches
pkg
prepare
repair
requirements
rtfm
rubygems
rvm
set
snapshot
tools
upgrade
version
wrapper
zsh
```

My `~/.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
#...not important stuff

source ~/.bashrc

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

And in my `~/.bashrc` I have this line (and few others):

```
[ -s "/Users/amorfis/.scm_breeze/scm_breeze.sh" ] && source "/Users/amorfis/.scm_breeze/scm_breeze.sh"
```

When I remove this line, the error is also gone. And again, it still doesn't show when I run `source ~/.scm_breeze/scm_breeze.sh`

Scm breeze is installed from here: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze

In `source ~/.scm_breeze/scm_breeze.sh` there is such piece of code:

```
if ! type ruby > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Now in if"
  # If Ruby is not installed, fall back to the
  # slower bash/zsh implementation of 'git_status_shortcuts'
  source "$scmbDir/lib/git/fallback/status_shortcuts_shell.sh"
fi
```

I expected the "if" statement is the problem. So I did this. Added such code before the if:

```
echo "Now lets try"
if ! type ruby > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "trying"
fi
echo "tried"
```

and inside if, as the first line in the block:
    echo "Now in if"

This was the output:

```
Now lets try
tried
-bash: /Users/amorfis/.rvm/scripts/cd: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/amorfis/.rvm/scripts/cd: line 14: `    cd()    { __zsh_like_cd cd    "$@" ; }'
```

So it looks like scm_breeze.sh is ok. The problem must be in .rvm, but only when scm_breeze.sh is run.

UPDATE 2:

The beginning of the `.rvm/scripts/cd` script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Source a .rvmrc file in a directory after changing to it, if it exists.  To
# disable this feature, set rvm_project_rvmrc=0 in /etc/rvmrc or $HOME/.rvmrc
case "${rvm_project_rvmrc:-1}" in
1|cd)
  # clonned from git@github.com:mpapis/bash_zsh_support.git
  source "$rvm_scripts_path/extras/bash_zsh_support/chpwd/function.sh"

  # not using default loadign to support older Zsh
  [[ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]] &&
  __rvm_version_compare "$ZSH_VERSION" -gt  4.3.4 ||
  {
    cd()    { __zsh_like_cd cd    "$@" ; }
    popd()  { __zsh_like_cd popd  "$@" ; }
    pushd() { __zsh_like_cd pushd "$@" ; }
  }
```

Comment: There's no error when you manually run that source line but there is when it is run automatically from your `.bash_profile`? What other files are in the `.rvm/scripts/` directory? What else is in your `.bash_profile` file (right before that source ling)?

Comment: Can you include the contents of that `cd` script? It is bizarre that an unrelated source line could change the error message. (I assume you meant that if you leave the rvm sourcing and remove just the scm-breeze sourcing the error goes away? Does rvm work at that point?)

Comment: Updated the question. I installed zsh, and there is no problem there, but when I run bash, and in bash I run `source ~/bash_profile` there is error, but only the first time it's run.

Comment: What version of bash are you using? (I've got no good idea what might be going on here.)

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Two years later - i get this error while trying to cd into a directory via ftp . . .

Answer (score 3):

I'd add this in as a comment, but I don't have the reputation to do so. I tried the answer from blob, but it didn't work.

I don't see the "`scm_breeze`-line", that Riaan Burger was talking about. **Has anyone figured out an answer to this?**

My error is pretty much the same:

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/scripts/cd:14: defining function based on alias `cd'                                                       [ruby-2.3.3]
/Users/myusername/.rvm/scripts/cd:14: parse error near `()'
```

and line #14 says the same:

```
11      [[ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]] &&
12      __rvm_version_compare "$ZSH_VERSION" -gt  4.3.4 ||
13      {
14        cd()    { __zsh_like_cd cd    "$@" ; }
15        popd()  { __zsh_like_cd popd  "$@" ; }
16        pushd() { __zsh_like_cd pushd "$@" ; }
17      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. The solution was to ensure the scm_breeze line executes after all the rvm ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same problem today, but the problem had nothing to do with `scm_breeze` in my case. If anyone stumbled onto this answer from google or some other place, maybe it'll help you.

Shortly after switching to OSX from Win7 I've been happily modifying anything and everything without necessarily understanding what I'm doing. Amongst other things, I've edited `.bashrc` as root (not the one from profile, rather the one located in `/etc/.bashrc`) and aliased `cd` like that:

```
alias cd='cd -P'
```

Never had problems with it before installing RVM, so if you were as root-happy as I once was, it might be worth checking whether you left yourself such a gift in the past.

I've moved said line into `~/.bash_profile` and since then RVM happily runs without errors.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I did,

Step 1) Get a clone from [SCM_BREEZE](https://github.com/scmbreeze/scm_breeze) :-

```
git clone https://github.com/scmbreeze/scm_breeze.git
```

Step 2) Get a reference from Author's Doc ([Link for Docs](https://madebynathan.com/2011/10/19/git-shortcuts-like-youve-never-seen-before/)) and wrote few commands inside my local git repository's terminal,

```
. "$HOME/.scm_breeze/scm_breeze.sh"

update_scm_breeze

gs
```

- It will update you scm breeze from github and patch your files if any
- Your Git Status Command

N you are good to go...

Hope so it would help you now :)